# Scrapy Start_url error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy i am trying to scrape date from the pages of range(1,70000000)
the code I is used is

```
import scrapy, json, re
from blackberry.items import BlackberryItem
class BlackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'datas'
    start_urls = [
              'https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482' %page for page in xrange(1, 10000000),
              'https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482'%y for y in xrange(10000000, 20000000),
              'https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482'%a for a in xrange(20000000, 30000000),
              'https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482'%b for b in xrange(40000000, 50000000),
              'https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482'%c for c in xrange(50000000, 60000000),
              'https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482'%d for d in xrange(60000000, 70000000)
              ]
```

But i got this error :

```
"y is not defined"
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is as follow.

```
import scrapy
import json
import re
from blackberry.items import BlackberryItem
class BlackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'datas'
    start_urls = ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482' % page for page in xrange(10000000, 20000000)]
    start_urls += ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482' % page for page in xrange(20000000, 30000000)]
    start_urls += ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482' % page for page in xrange(30000000, 40000000)]
    start_urls += ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482' % page for page in xrange(40000000, 50000000)]
    start_urls += ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/content/%s?countryid=100&lang=en&callback=_content_2360&_=1499177414482' % page for page in xrange(50000000, 60000000)]
```

Comment: There is not sufficient memory. you need to start with a smaller range.